# What am I doing wrong with this derivative - Differential calculus (brush up)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

today I felt like doing some maths and I thought to myself that practicing some derivatives would be neat-o.

I sat myself the following question. $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{5x^4+4x^3+3x^2+2x+1}{x^3}\right)$$Here are my thought process to the problem:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(5x+4+\frac{3}{x}+\frac{2}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$
$$5+\frac{d}{dx}(3x^{-1}+2x^{-2}+x^{-3})$$
$$5-3x^{-2}-4x^{-3}-3x^{-4}$$
Which then if you will could be rewritten again to the perhaps more beautiful
$$5-\frac{3}{x^2}-\frac{4}{x^3}-\frac{3}{x^4}$$ Finally my question is, why is this incorrect?

Comment: It looks fine to me (other than the typo where you wrote $\frac{x}{3}$ instead of $\frac{1}{x^3}$ which has now been fixed) Why do you think that it is incorrect?

Comment: It isn't incorrect.

Comment: @Dylan, thanks for the correction.. Well, I first checked with WolframAlpha, it said $d/dx((5 x^4+4 x^3+3 x^2+2 x+1)/x^3) = -(-5 x^4+3 x^2+4 x+3)/x^4$, and with Maple which gave an entirely different answer, so I figured my result was wrong, I have now checked my result: $d/(dx)(5 x^4+4 x^3+3 x^2+2 x+1)/x^3 = 5-3/x^2-4/x^3-3/x^4$, which gave the result true on WolframAlpha, which goes to show I should maybe believe a bit more in myself, however I'm still curious to why it interpreted $\frac{d}{dx}$ as the partial derivative instead..

Comment: Your answer and Wolfram Alpha's is the same. It just put everything over a common denominator. (And factored out a $-1$ for some reason) I'm sure Maple's answer is also the same if you do some algebra and rewrite it.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct. You can pull it all together into a single fraction.

$$\frac{5x^4-3x^2-4x-3}{x^4}.$$

Comment: Thanks, I missed that too initially when I verified my result! :-)